# Spring MVC Filter solution

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc

I need your suggestions on filter usage. Just wanted to know what I am thinking
is a good possible way.
So I have been tasked with developing 5-6 screens using JSP, Spring MVC 2.5, javascript etc etc.
 All
these screens share lot of common data elements such as dropdown lists etc.
 I was thinking
of implementing a filter and populating these dropdown values inside a spring ModelMap
right there in the filter so that every screen that falls under the filter's URL pattern
gets this data.
Is this a right approach?

Comment: Filter?  absolutely not.  Spring interceptor, perhaps, but I would personally be disinclined to so grossly violate the principle of least surprise in pursuit of an overly-micro approach to code-reuse.  Put the code in a utility class and call it from an @ModelAttribute method on each controller.

Comment: @Affe I agree with the interceptor approach I have successfully implemented this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Affe. micro code reuse approach was my target :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe a filter would do the trick, however I would stay away from this approach. You could also use Spring's interceptors to do the same thing and still utilize the features of Spring such as dependency injection, transaction management and the Spring Data packages.

In your configuration for the dispatcher setup the interceptor.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
       <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
       <bean class="org.my.domain.interceptors.LookupHandlerInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Then define your interceptor class:

```
public class LookupHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

        @Autowired
        LookupLoaderApplicationListener loader;

        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
             request.setAttribute("lookupList", loader.getCategories());
             return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
        }
    }
```

This approach would allow you to take advantage of other Spring features you may be using within your application such as any persistence you may have setup.  Then you could manage this list within your database.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I think to persist data in model attribute I have to use @SessionAttributes along with modelMap to persist it between multiple requests.

Answer (score 1):

I think violating the principle of least surprise and hiding code that is critical to the correct function of a controller in a separate part of the application is not worth whatever bit of "magic"/cleverness is squeezed out of doing this.

Why hide the code that sets up the screens from future developers?

Just because they all share common reference data now, will they forever and for all time?  As soon as the requirements for the different screens start to diverge, it gets ugly fast.

You basically have all the drawbacks of using inheritance instead of composition to make a controller, plus on top of that you can't even see the code from the controller.  I would simply make a utility bean that does the common work, inject it on the controller, and write the one line `@ModelAttribute` method to call it.  There will be much less mess when their individual requirements change in the future.